# Python genfromtxt cannot import file from local machine to google colab

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory, genfromtxt

I am just trying to import a .txt file from my D: drive of my windows machine to google colab using genfromtxt() of numpy from python. But I cannot find a way to import. All I get is error "File not found" as the current working directory is point to google drive.
Please provide a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change your path settings. Try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(the_desired_file_location)
```

Comment: no good, still this os.getcwd() gives the output as '/content', i.e to the google drive